# My code isn't pulling the information from parse.com using Parse Query

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parse-platform

So I have a list view that loads all users given certain criteria is met. Now I'm trying to get it where when a user click on the user's item it pulls up that user profile just like any other social network. So I'm using parse.com as my backend and I got it where an Intent pulls the objectId from the clicked user and will put it in the intent like so

```
usersList.setAdapter (usersAdapter);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            GamingProfile profile = usersAdapter.getItem (position);

            try {
                profile.getGamer ().getObjectId ();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }

            openProfile (profile);

        }
    });


    return v;
}
```

and here is the method for openProfile

```
 public void openProfile (GamingProfile profile) {

    profile = usersAdapter.getItem (0);

    Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity (), ViewUserProfile.class);

    intent.putExtra ("USERS_ID", profile.getId ());

    startActivity (intent);

    Toast.makeText (getActivity (),
                        "Found user",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

        }
```

But when I get to the ViewUserProfile activity nothing loads into the fields. Here is my code below:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent ();
    usersId = intent.getStringExtra ("USERS_ID");
    String currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser ().getObjectId ();


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery ("GamingProfile");
    query.include ("gamer");
    query.whereNotEqualTo (usersId, currentUserId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject> () {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // The query was successful.
                for(ParseObject thisUser : objects){
                    lolIdSting = thisUser.getString("leagueOfLegendsId");
                    psnIdString = thisUser.getString("playStationId");
                    xboxIdString = thisUser.getString ("xboxId");

                    try {
                        vuserProfilePictureView.setProfileId (gProfile.getJSONObject ("profile").getString ("facebookId"));
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace ();
                    }

                    try {
                        vuserGenderView.setText (gProfile.getJSONObject ("profile").getString ("name"));
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace ();
                    }

                    try {
                        vuserNameView.setText (gProfile.getJSONObject ("profile").getString ("name"));
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace ();
                    }

                }

                vuserLoLId.setText (lolIdSting);
                vuserPsnId.setText (psnIdString);
                vuserXboxId.setText (xboxIdString);

            } else {
                // Something went wrong.
                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "Error in getting user data_"
                        + e.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();

                Log.d (GamerzioApplication.TAG, "Error parsing saved user data.");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I tried debugging the openProfile and I get no objectId back, so I'm guessing I'm not getting the objectId from the adapter but I don't how to retrieve it based of the item click yet.

```
public void openProfile (GamingProfile profile) {

    try {
        if (profile.getGamer ().has ("objectId")) {

        Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity (), ViewUserProfile.class);

        intent.putExtra ("USERS_ID", profile.getId ());

        startActivity (intent);

        Toast.makeText (getActivity (),
                "Found user",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    } else {

            Toast.makeText (getActivity (), "No objectId", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }

}
```

Here is my LIstAdapter

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<GamingProfile> {


static ParseUser currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser ().getParseUser ("gamer");

public static TextView userProfileName;

public UsersAdapter(final Context context) {
    super (context, new QueryFactory<GamingProfile> () {
        @Override
        public ParseQuery<GamingProfile> create() {
            ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery ("GamingProfile");

            query.whereNotEqualTo ("gamer", currentUserId);

            query.orderByDescending ("gamer");


            return query;
        }
    });
}



@Override
public View getItemView(GamingProfile gamingProfile, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate (getContext (), R.layout.user_list_item, null);
    }

    super.getItemView (gamingProfile, v, parent);

    final ProfilePictureView userProfilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView)
            v.findViewById (R.id.profileImageItem);

    try {
        userProfilePictureView.setProfileId (gamingProfile.getGamer ().getJSONObject ("profile").getString ("facebookId"));
    } catch (JSONException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }

     userProfileName = (TextView)
            v.findViewById (R.id.userItemName);


    try {
        userProfileName.setText (gamingProfile.getGamer ().getJSONObject ("profile").getString ("name"));
    } catch (JSONException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }


    return v;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to debug the code and make sure you pass the right USER_ID? 
In **openProfile**, you pass a profile but then you override it with

> profile = usersAdapter.getItem (0);

Also, make sure your profiles in the adapter contains IDs.

Comment: I attempted to debug it it seems that I'm not getting the clicked item users objectId.

Comment: you need to shows us how you populate your list/adapter. Also, you might need to show the implementation of **GamingProfile**.

Also, why you test for `if (profile.getGamer ().has ("objectId")) ` and then user another method to get the id `intent.putExtra ("USERS_ID", profile.getId ());`